# Из ByteBufferNB в string

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть ByteBuffer на вход

```js
ByteBuffer {
  buffer: <Buffer 08 df c6 01 12 95 01 09 6e d0 0f 0e 01 00 10 01 10 01 18 00 20 00 28 00 30 00 38 01 40 01 7a 1d d0 a2 d0 b8 d1 80 d0 b0 d0 bd d0 be d0 b7 d0 b0 d0 b2 ... >,
  offset: 136,
  markedOffset: -1,
  limit: 136,
  littleEndian: true,
  noAssert: false }
```

При обычно toString()
выводит

```js
��� ]�� (08@ARTRODEX�����BT��fg36�
p�^��å���Ƌ������:��
status#DOTA_RP_PLAYING_AS�$
steam_display#DOTA_RP_PLAYING_AS�

num_params3�
EventTrophyLevel2�
WatchableGameID0�
EventPoints_22224065�&
param0#DOTA_lobby_type_name_ranked�

param125�
param2#npc_dota_hero_sniper��
```

Comment: код приложите, пожалуйста.

Comment: нажмите кнопку `править` под текстом вопроса и вставьте код в него. Комментарии читают не все пользователи, более того в комментарии  вы не можете его оформить должным образом.

Comment: @МихаилРебров , готово

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что это можно привести к строке?

Comment: @AlexeyTen там точно что-то должно быть. Хотел посмотреть что с помощью строки.